# same code, different order if tie exists in priority_queue, using clang and gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, std, priority-queue

wise guys

My question was like this:

I need to use priority_queue from std, everything works fine, until if there exists ties between my records, the order is no long consistent if I compile using clang compared to compiling on gcc.

my comparator function is simple:

```
bool comparator(const max_pair_t &lhs, const max_pair_t &rhs) {
    return lhs.pval < rhs.pval; 
}
```

that's it.

Is there a way to resolve this problem?

PS: I printed out all the records using two binary excutables, and compared the order side by side, the order is different, but the tied records are in the neighboring area

Comment: Can you first please convince us that there *is* a problem? Which part of the standard made you believe that there is a portable order among tied elements in a heap? Are you sure you actually want a priority queue, and not some other data structure?

Comment: If they have the same priority, what difference does it make what order they're processed in?

Comment: @Barmar Because I need the result to be reproducible, most importantly, I need both versions generate consistent result.

Comment: Then you need to use something more consistent for the comparator.

Comment: @Barmar I can workaround, but I wonder if this is widely known and expected to be different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::priority_queue` gives no guarantees about sort stability. If you need sort stability, you'll have to provide it yourself, e.g. by storing a progressively increasing or decreasing value (doesn't really matter which, it just changes the direction of the fallback comparison) that is used when the primary comparison key is equal, and stripping it off when you pop off the queue.